# StackOverflow when calling form from class

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

I am getting a `StackOverflowException` when I am calling my form from my class.

In my `MainForm` I call the `Youtube.cs` class using this, `Youtube yt = new Youtube();`. Then in my `Youtube` class I call the `MainForm` using, `MainForm main = new MainForm();`. I believe this is what is causing the StackOverflow as it seems to be creating a loop.

I need to access the `Youtube` class from `MainForm` and also `MainForm` from my `Youtube` class so is there any way around this without causing the StackOverflow?

This is the from the top of `MainForm`:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Youtube yt = new Youtube();
```

And this is from the top of `Youtube.cs`:

```
class Youtube
{
    MainForm main = new MainForm();
```

Comment: can you show some code? We need to see how each class "Accesses" the other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass form object to YouTube class, and use the object in YouTube class.

```
public class Youtube
{
     MainForm m_MainForm = null;
     public Youtube(MainForm frm)
     {
            m_MainForm = frm;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is causing the `StackOverFlowException`.

One way is to pass the Form into your `Youtube` class via the constructor.

---

**Example:**

in the `MainForm` class:

```
Youtube yt = new Youtube(this)

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        yt = new Youtube(this);
    }

    Youtube yt = null;
```

in the `Youtube` class:

```
public Youtube(MainForm mainform)
{
    // do something with mainform
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass your `MainForm` to your `YouTube` class as a parameter.

```
public class MainForm
{
   private Youtube youtube;
   public MainForm()
   {
       youtube = new Youtube(this);
   }
}
```

And then in you `Youtube` class store this reference:

```
public class Youtube
{
   private MainForm form;

   public Youtube(MainForm form)
   {
       this.form = form;
   }
}
```